# Excel Mac (Office 11): Sum cells within a row that meet heading criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a formula that will sum cells in a row for those cells with column  headings (number 1 to...n) that fall within a range, say 2 to 4  or 3 to 9.  The critera for the column heading would be two other cells. Let's say row 15 is an an array with column headings 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.  If the criteria were column headings 3 and 6, the formula would sum the cells from row 15 with column headings between 3 and 6. Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your criteria are in cells A1 and B1 and range to sum is A16:J16 the formula is: `=SUMIFS(A16:J16,A15:J15,">="&A1,A15:J15,"<="&B1)`.